# ORA-28040 When install Oracle EM12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to install Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c but i'm stuck here [image]

I have tried to edit Listener.ora and tnsname.ora , here is my **lsnrctl status**
[image]
Here is my LISTENER

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = exampledb.trongnhan185.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

And when i login by SQL Developer it still success , so i think my database cannot down , the problem i think it is about **LISTENER**.What should I do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the unsupported combination of JDBC/JDK/Database components. The reason for this is mismatching of the authentication protocol with the JDBC client and the Oracle database server.

Normally the problem lies in the fact that both Oracle 10g and 11g use SHA-1 protocol whereas Oracle 12c and higher uses SHA-2 protocol. While SHA-2 protocol by itself is not causing the error, it is the default setting for SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER that is causing the error. In earlier versions, the default was 8 whereas it is 11 in Oracle 12c;

You must include this line in your sqlnet.ora file

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10
```

But, if you still got the error, try to do the following: Delete the ojdbc14.jar file and used ojdbc6.jar instead. It could do the trick.

Regards